# Accessing array from listener

Tags: javascript

In my typescript code in a method I have following code

```
var myArray = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), 'set_at', function(index, obj) {
   console.log('Vertex moved on outer path.');
   console.log(obj.lat() ,'--',  obj.lng() );
   myArray= poly.getPath().getArray();
});
```

This event listener will be called again and again when user clicks on google map. I want to access myArray in another method in my typescript code and get the latest value of it. How can I do that?

Comment: where did you get your poly variable?

Comment: it is from google map lib. I just want to have data in  myArray outside this

Comment: is there any error? can you post it also?

Comment: There is no error. I am just not able to access data of myArray outside this piece of code. I want to access this  myArray in anothter method. How to do that?